# Steps to setting up my first eCommerce site

Tags: php, javascript, html, e-commerce

I'm about set up my first eCommerce site. I was hoping you could recommend some shopping cart software. What are the perks of using pre-built software rather than developing some simple solution catered to my needs. Also, are there pre-written Terms and conditions for sites? Or templates that outline what aspects need to be addressed? What other things should I look out for when building this website?

Also, I develop in PHP server side, so software in that language would be best.

Comment: This probably belongs on serverfault.com.  Running an eCommerce site requires more than just getting the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wound up writing my own shopping cart software because the site is not based in the U.S. and services like PayPal and Google Checkout do not cover it. I coupled my cart with an API from a national bank to charge credit cards. This required SSL which was easy enough to set up.

I found a [Terms and Conditions generator](http://www.bennadel.com/coldfusion/privacy-policy-generator.htm) online and used that to lay out the basics of the document. Then I added site specifics myself and tried to sound as much like a lawyer as possible.

Comment: don't know where you are situated, but paypal covers most of the world's countries, at least pretty much every european country

Answer (score 2):

I use osCommerce a lot, but this software is a bit outdated. Magento is a good alternative for setting up a commerce website.

Comment: +1 for magento, please do not use oscommerce, as it is, like @Marien said, pretty outdated. Furthermore, magento is extensive and flexible (it can be anything you want)

Answer (score 0):

Google Checkout is probably a good starting point for a clean base to start from: http://checkout.google.com/sell/.

Answer (score 0):

The hands down easiest all in one ecommerce platform IMO is the Yahoo Small Business platform - you have a number of options there, including using hosting and php. It's not free, but you get EVERYTHING you need to run an eCommerce store all in one painless spot - your cart, ssl, content management, integration for merchant gateway, shipping rules, integration with ups realtime rates... Order processing, the whole nine.

There are two ways to develop on this platform - using their proprietary RTML language, or use the hosting that you get with it and access the items in your catalog through what they call store tags.

Answer (score 0):

I second Yahoo! Small Business (although I would get a developer, their default template looks horrible). If you are looking for something that looks nice and is out of the box good to go, Bigcommerce would be my second choice. After that, I would go with 3dcart (it's a little more flexible, but the default themes are not as good as what Bigcommerce offers). Although, if you are a hardcore programmer, going with Drupal Commerce would probably be your best bet, but you will really need to know some programming to customize it. On the plus side, it is the only cart that I have mentioned that is free (minus hosting costs of course).